# Login user using wp_signon and WP_User object

Tags: login

The problem is that `wp_signon` function requires password as plain text. Where `WP_User` object returns user password as hashed.

There is any way to safety login using user WP_User object? Something like this:

```
$user = new WP_User(1);

wp_signon([
    'user_login' => $user->user_login,
    'user_password' => $user->user_pass,
    'remember' => true,
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`wp_set_auth_cookie`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_auth_cookie/):

```
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, ( bool ) $remember );
```

Comment: It is safe? I don't see any password validation or hash parring. Basically it bypass all verification done in normal login.

Comment: Yes because there is nothing to verify - you already have the user ID that you want to log in, it's on _you_ to make sure it's okay to do so.

Comment: Perfect solution.